# How do I find optimal ω for SOR method?

Tags: integration, matrices, proof-verification, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Following is the example from [this](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=49OKMwCL7CkC&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=%CF%89%20%3D%202%201%20%2B%201%20%E2%88%92%20%5B%CF%81(Tj)%5D2&source=bl&ots=pFoR_f-ENp&sig=j6Ra3-BSoDcWOUMQH_QTC2_O9Xo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEqubnv6DKAhXQHI4KHbHbCL0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%CF%89%20%3D%202%201%20%2B%201%20%E2%88%92%20%5B%CF%81(Tj)%5D2&f=false) book.
My question is, what value of λ did he put in? He did not explain that, can anybody explain how did he get `1.24`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the matrix $T_j$, he calculates the eigenvalues. We have the characteristic polynomial:

$$\tag 1 \det(T_j - \lambda I) = -\lambda(\lambda^2 -0.625) \implies \lambda_{1,2,3} = 0, \pm \sqrt{0.625}$$

The spectral radius is given by the maximum magnitude eigenvalue:

$$\rho(A) = \displaystyle \max ~ |\lambda_i| $$

From $(1)$, we have:

$$\rho(T_j) = \displaystyle \max ~ |\lambda_i| = \sqrt{0.625}$$

Now, when $A$ is positive definite and tridiagonal, we have:

$$\omega = \dfrac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - [\rho(T_j)]^2}}$$

The calculation follows.

There is a write-up of the theory of this choice in [*Section 3*](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~gobbert/papers/YangGobbertAML2007.pdf).

Comment: But what if the spectral radius is greater than 1? The expression inside the square root will become negative and hence $\omega$ becomes imaginary?

Comment: @AditiNarware: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390456/matrix-with-spectral-radius-greater-or-equal-1-such-that-fixed-point-iteration-c

Comment: @AditiNarware: Also see page $7$ of http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/ExamplesToIterativeMethods.pdf